# How to find a specific string in .txt file using BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, string, file

I have a task to search all .txt files for a specific word and then print all files containing that word. I have this code which finds all .txt files, and I just need to add check if that word is in, but with using BufferedReader import. I'm new in Java and I'd be happy if you help me.

```
package thenewboston.tutorials;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class apples30 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("D:\\test");
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.lastIndexOf('.')>0) {
                      int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                      String str = name.substring(lastIndex);
                      if(str.equals(".txt")) {
                         return true;
                      }
                   }
                return false;
            }
        };
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);

        for(File x: listOfFiles) {
            System.out.println(x.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my code looks now.

Comment: Please try reading your files using BufferedReader first. Then post the code that you tried, along with a description of where you are stuck

Comment: That is a problem, I don't know how to read a file with BufferedReader, there are some examples, but I don't understand them. And I need to read more files, no just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the files and use .contains("specific word") (a string method that will return true if the string contains that specific word).